# Conversion Big Integer <-> double in C++

Tags: c++, math, assembly

I am writing my own long arithmetic library in C++ for fun and it is already pretty finished, I even implemented several Cryptogrphic algorithms with that library, but one important thing is still missing: I want to convert doubles (and floats/long doubles) into my number and vice versa. My numbers are represented as a variable sized array of unsigned long ints plus a sign bit.

I tried to find the answer with google, but the problem is that people rarely ever implement such things themselves, so I only find things about how to use Java BigInteger etc.

Conceptually, it is rather easy: I take the mantissa, shift it by the number of bits dictated by the exponent and set the sign. In the other direction I truncate it so that it fits into the mantissa and set the exponent depending on my log2 function.

But I am having a hard time to figure out the details, I could either play around with some bit patterns and cast it to a double, but I didn't find an elegant way to achieve that or I could "calculate" it by starting with 2, exponentiate, multiply etc, but that doesn't seem very efficient.

I would appreciate a solution that doesn't use any library calls because I am trying to avoid libraries for my project, otherwise I could just have used gmp, furthermore, I often have two solutions on several other occasions, one using inline assembler which is efficient and one that is more platform independent, so either answer is useful for me.

edit: I use uint64_t for my parts, but I would like to be able to change it depending on the machine, but I am willing to do some different implementations with some #ifdefs to achieve that.

Comment: Does avoiding any library calls include calls to the standard library (in particular the math library)?

Comment: Maybe looking at this code will help you: https://gist.github.com/f29a0a7813df398fc494 Note that this is for floats, you'll still have to adapt it for doubles, of course.

Comment: I use a few such standard library calls elsewhere, e.g for the conversions of long ints <-> strings, so it is not "forbidden", but I prefer a solution without to a solution with library calls. Thanks for the link nightcracker, looks very useful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to make non-portable assumption here: namely, that `unsigned long long` has more accurate digits than `double`.  (This is true on all modern desktop systems that I know of.)

First, convert the most significant integer(s) into an `unsigned long long`.  Then convert that to a double `S`.  Let `M` be the number of integers less than those used in that first step.  multiply `S` by`(1ull << (sizeof(unsigned)*CHAR_BIT*M)`.  (If shifting more than 63 bits, you will have to split those into seperate shifts and do some alrithmetic)  Finally, if the original number was negative you multiply this result by -1.

This rounds a lot, but even with this rounding, due to the above assumption, no digits are lost that wouldn't be lost anyway with the conversion to a double.  I think this is a similar process to what Mark Ransom said, but I'm not certain.

For converting from a double to a biginteger, first seperate the mantissa into a `double M` and the exponent into an `int E`, using `frexp`.  Multiply `M` by `UNSIGNED_MAX`, and store that result in an `unsigned R`.  If `std::numeric_limits<double>::radix()` is 2 (I don't know if it is or not for x86/x64), you can easily shift `R` left by `E-(sizeof(unsigned)*CHAR_BIT)` bits and you're done. Otherwise the result will instead be`R*(E**(sizeof(unsigned)*CHAR_BIT))` (where `**` means to the power of)

If performance is a concern, you can add an overload to your bignum class for multiplying by `std::constant_integer<unsigned, 10>`, which simply returns `(LHS<<4)+(LHS<<2)`.  You can similarly optimize other constants if you wish.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be a good solution for the Bigint -> Float direction which can even easily made portable by using some #ifdefs. I don't know how efficient pow is, maybe one could improve it by using the knowledge that we create a power of two and play with the exponent of the float somehow.

Comment: Good call, removed `pow` in favor of a bitshift.  Far faster.  if the bitshift would be bigger than 64 bits, I don't think a double could hold the value anyway. (not certain about that)

Comment: oh!  I totally didn't realize you also wanted double->bigint, I'll add that as soon as I think of how

Comment: Alright, I don't know if x86 doubles have a radix of 2 or not, so there's two ways.  One is easy and fast, the other is harder and slower.

Comment: Sorry, I think I confused you with the shift. 2 << 100 can easily be stored into a double and into a BigInt, but your shift would not work, I just meant that it would be better to modify the exponent directly than to use pow. But thanks for frexp, I also found ldexp and those two answer my question how I can elegantly access the exponent and the mantissa separately.

Comment: Why wouldn't my shift work? (Yes, it'd have to be in a BigInt before the shift)

Comment: I mean the first shift in the BigInt -> Double direction. If you convert to BigInt, you cannot multiply it with a double any more.

Comment: @user1655480: I'm not _certain_, but I think if that shift would fail, then the `double` cannot hold the value anyway.

Comment: I don't think so, 2^128 can be represented by a double without error, but the shift would fail.

Comment: alright, in that case you'll have to multiply by (1ull<<60) a few times first to bring the remainder into a valid range.

Answer (score 1):

This blog post might help you  [Clarifying and optimizing Integer>>asFloat](http://smallissimo.blogspot.fr/2011/09/clarifying-and-optimizing.html)

Otherwise, you can yet have an idea of algorithm with this SO question [Converting from unsigned long long to float with round to nearest even](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400747/converting-from-unsigned-long-long-to-float-with-round-to-nearest-even/11058796#11058796)

Comment: Thanks, they both gave me some additional hints for my implementation. Sorry I first overlooked your post.

Answer (score 0):

To go from a big integer to a double, just do it the same way you parse numbers. For example, you parse the number "531" as "1 + (3 * 10) + (5 * 100)". Compute each portion using doubles, starting with the least significant portion.

To go from a double to a big integer, do it the same way but in reverse starting with the most significant portion. So, to convert 531, you first see that it's more than 100 but less than 1000. You find the first digit by dividing by 100. Then you subtract to get the remainder of 31. Then find the next digit by dividing by 10. And so on.

Of course, you won't be using tens (unless you store your big integers as digits). Exactly how you break it apart depends on how your big integer class is constructed. For example, if it's uses 64-bit units, then you'll use powers of 2^64 instead of powers of 10.

Comment: Your conversion from big integer to double works, but it gets inefficient for large numbers. If the number has size n, it takes O(n) operations, but I think the conversion should be doable in constant time.

For the other direction I don't really understand how this works for floats.

Comment: It's not O(n), it's O(log n). (1,000 has 4 digits you must process. 10,000 has 5 digits you must process.) And it's trivially provable that no operation faster than O(log n) can exist. The big integer contains O(log n) bytes of data, and each such byte must be processed in at least some way.

Comment: It is O(n) if I define n to be the size of the input as I did. No, your proof doesn't work. Just mentioning that every byte must be processed is not sufficient for a proof, it is crucial for these kind of proofs that you show me that if an algorithm doesn't look at the ith byte, it is incorrect for some values for the ith byte, i.e. that the result depends on every byte. This is not the case here. Because of the limited precision of double, it is sufficient to look at the few most significant bytes only, so constant time is possible, you don't have to look at the other bytes.

Comment: Nothing about my algorithm prevents you from stopping early in the double->integer case. As for the integer->double case, you have to figure out where to start, which is a little more complicated. (Whether this permits an algorithm that's not O(log n) depends on the details of your big integer implementation.)

Comment: Ok, true, I should have been more clear that my worries about the O(n) operations only applied to the first algorithm. But in the way you descriped it, you start with the least significant portion, that is why I thought you need O(n) operations.

Comment: No, this algorithm doesn't work. Imagine we have a number rounded at 1 digit, tie to nearest even: 346 will be reconstructed as 6, 46 rounded to 50, then 350 rounded to 400, though 300 were the nearest representable number to 346. Same thing will happen with float/double when several round off errors will cumulate, you won't always get nearest float/double. It's exactly the mistake I corrected in Smalltalk.

Comment: @aka.nice: You don't round 46 to 50 but to 4. You can't round 350 to 400 but to 3. You always round down.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz they are float/double and this is governed by IEEE rounding mode which defaults to round to nearest, tie to even. But if you set the rounding mode to truncate, then yes you can.

Comment: @aka.nice: I actually think it doesn't matter in this case. There's only one floating point unit. If you were doing arbitrary-precision floating point, then it would matter.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz in Smalltalk it did matter. This algorithm LargeInteger->Float did prevent correct decimal String -> Float conversion (aka scanf), despite Smalltalk had arbitrary integer precision from ages... Bad for inter-operability, and portability, several different implementations in several dialects -> several results for same decimal String.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say explicitly, but I assume your library is integer only and the unsigned longs are 32 bit and binary (not decimal). The conversion *to* double is simple, so I'll tackle that first.

Start with a multiplier for the current piece; if the number is positive it will be 1.0, if negative it will be -1.0. For each of the unsigned long ints in your bignum, multiply by the current multiplier and add it to the result, then multiply your multiplier by `pow(2.0, 32)` (4294967296.0) for 32 bits or `pow(2.0, 64)` (18446744073709551616.0) for 64 bits.

You can optimize this process by working with only the 2 most significant values. You need to use 2 even if the number of bits in your integer type is larger than the precision of a double, since the number of *used* bits in the most significant value might only be 1. You can generate the multiplier by taking a power of 2 to the number of skipped bits, e.g. `pow(2.0, most_significant_count*sizeof(bit_array[0])*8)`. You can't use a bit shift as given in another answer because it will overflow after the first value.

To convert from double, you can get the exponent and mantissa separated from each other with the `frexp` function. The mantissa will come as a floating point value between 0.5 and 1.0 so you'll want to multiply it by pow(2.0, 32) or pow(2.0, 64) to convert it to an integer, then adjust the exponent by -32 or -64 to compensate.

Comment: I used uint64_t on my machine, but I want to keep the option of using something else. The problem with your solution is, that it takes O(n) time if n is the size of the number and I think it should be doable in constant time.

Comment: @user1655480, I think Mooing Duck has the right idea - you should only need the most significant 1 or 2 values to saturate the precision of a double.